# How to redirect user to login page when user is not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When user is logged in we store its user id in the session.

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

now on all other links in our site, we want the user redirected if `session[:user_id] == nil`

The way I think it would be done is that it will be done in each of the methods of controller.

```
def show_customers
   if session[:user_id] == nil
     redirect_to (:controller => "authentication", :action => "login")
   #code related to show_customers goes here
end
```

but this will need to be done in every method of every controller.

Is there a more sane Rails'y way to do this?

Comment: I think I say this on every question to do with authentication, but I hope you're using a readily available library like clearance.  If not, you should be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [before_filter](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use a before_filter to validate the session is valid, and if you dont want to put it in every controller, put it in your application_controller (since all controllers inherit from it).  You can also easily exclude/restrict the actions its called for by overriding the method in your controllers.

Comment: Or create an Admin controller and inherit the 'protected controllers' from this controller. (And ofcourse put the before_filter and methods in the Admin Controller)