# redirect to login page if user not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my user to be redirected to the login form if he is not logged in ?

The thing is that I don't wanna do this for every action. I know there is a way so that I may define this for every controller only once ( i.e. something executes regardless of the action in my controller ) but I can't remember how.

Comment: Do you want it to run only on selected controllers/actions?

Comment: no, on everything . Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102941/how-to-redirect-user-to-login-page-when-user-is-not-logged-in

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use a [before_action](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action). Place the following in your application controller.

```
# application_controller.rb

before_action :require_login

private

  def require_login
    unless current_user
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
```

The code above assumes you have defined a method `current_user` which returns the user record when the user is logged in.

Then, in your login controller

```
skip_before_action :require_login
```

---

Comment: This won't work if I have a lot of controllers and actions in each, some of which requiring and some not requiring login yeah? Not all my actions require login. Is there another way?

Comment: @VictorPiousbox skip_before_filter accepts if/unless/only/except options.

Answer (score 5):

If you want login to be redirected only on particular controllers, then use:

```
skip_before_filter :require_login, :only=>[:edit,:update]
```

or:

```
skip_before_filter :require_login, :except=>[:new,:create]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your action_controller.rb as a before_filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise you can add a before_action helper to your controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers